# Call a method of the same object

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a js object with two functions. What is the right way to call `mySecondFunction()` from `myFirstFunction()`? Should it be this.mySecondFunction()? Or MyObject.mySecondFunction()?

I thought I would use "this", but if it is inside of an Event handler, then "this" refers to the DOM element and not to the object :(

```
var MyObject = {
  firstFunction: function() {
    whatgoeshere???.mySecondFunction();
  },

  secondFunction: function() {
    console.log('Hi!');
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling mySecondFunction()?  Because I only see functions firstFunction() and secondFunction().  No mySecondFunction().  this.secondFunction() should work.

Comment: OP would have mistyped MY - SecondFunction()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var MyObject = {
  firstFunction: function() {
    this.mySecondFunction();
  },

  secondFunction: function() {
    console.log('Hi!');
  },
  mySecondFunction: function() {
    alert('Hi!');
  }
}

MyObject.firstFunction();
```

**The above is what you intended to do**.

```
//declaring the constructor  
function MyObject() {  
    this.someProperty = 'whatever';        
}  
// declaring instance methods  
MyObject.prototype = {  
    firstFunction: function () {  
        this.secondFunction();  
    },  
    secondFunction: function () {  
        alert("Cool");  
    }  
};  

var am = new MyObject();    
am.firstFunction();
```

It's also a good idea to define the methods of your type using the prototype object, which is a property of the constructor function. The value of `this` will be the new object that you are trying to initialize.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's MyObject because it isn't an instance.

If you'ld have done something like:

```
var MyObject = function() {
};

MyObject.prototype.firstFunction = function() {
    this.secondFunction();
};

MyObject.prototype.secondFunction = function() {
    console.log('Hi!');
};

var instance = new MyObject();
instance.firstFunction();
```

Then, you create a new instance and can use `this`. In other words: the `this` refers to the current instance of an object